# How can I retrieve the number of comments and likes for carousel_album on Instagraph?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to retrieve the number of comments and likes for carousel_album on Instagraph, but there is only one metric available called total_interactions, which is the sum of comments and likes (I don't understand why it needs to be summed). Therefore, I cannot retrieve the number of comments and likes separately.
How can I retrieve the number of comments and likes for carousel_album on Instagraph?

Comment: Are you actually talking about doing anything with https://github.com/yoheinakajima/instagraph here - or are you just using the term "Instagraph" loosely (wrongly) - for the official Instagram APIs provided by Facebook?